# Switching dependent for independent variable in polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I've got this expression f(y) = $ax^2 + bnx + cn^2$

A basic polynomial.

given that i know the coefficients abc and that I can keep n const too, I have been trying to switching x and y since I believe this would be an interesting graph in my application.

I think it should be pretty trivial, I'm just failing at it. I've tried algebraically, but am pretty lost.

Hopefully somebody could provide me with some guidance as how to go about this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Is it $y=a x^2+bnx+cn^2$ and you want $x$ ?

Comment: yes, editing post thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=a x^2+bnx+cn^2$ and you want to extract $x$ as a function of $y$, you just need to solve the quadratic equation for $x$. Using the classical method (assuming  $a \ne 0$), you should find that $$x_{\pm}=\frac{-b n\pm \sqrt{n^2 \left(b^2-4 a c\right)+4 a y}}{2 a}$$

Comment: Ha! So just using the quadratic formula for solving 2. order equations gives you an expression for x. Why didn't I see that, I was thinking something like that was only for finding roots..

Comment: All quadratic expressions are not equal to $0$ ! Cheers :)